# How can I sign and add WS security in SOAP Request XML Programmatically in Java

Tags: java, soap

I want to sign a SOAPRequest XML string and add WS security in it programatically in java. I am able to sign a message by public key, but not able to add WS security manually in Java. How do I do this?